# How can we identify inputs and outputs of a logic gate application problem using Natural Language Processing?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

At the moment I have identified the entities in a given scenario, and I gave it a try to classify inputs entities and output entities using a neighborhood analysis technique for each identified entity. That method is not much accurate, since the way of providing the scenario might change time to time.

For an example:

- There is a **door**,**window** and a **safe**. The safe is unlocked , if the door
  is closed and the window is opened.

To find the Boolean expression for this we need to consider the safe, door and the window are entities.Furthermore the safe is an output entity and other two are input entities.

Can anyone suggest me a proper logic using python to identify which are input entities and which are output entities?

Comment: Is there any issue with this question? I would like to know if there as such and, willing to correct that issue.

Comment: seems to be a simple machine learning task

Comment: Can I solve this using a rule based approach rather than going to use ML approach?

Answer (score 1):

This task is not really a straightforward machine learning task.
You need to know where your inputs come from (webscraping, NL corpus, etc.)
and from this you have to abstract some patterns that match your input.
Maybe you could use some dependency parsing (instead of neighborhood and collocations) in order to extract the patterns and relations from corpus data. 
A logic compiler for python is pyke, you could check out whether you can use it.

Everything else seems to be straightforward propositional or predicate logic, so you should check out what resolution algorithms you can use to figure out the truth values of your scenarios.

If you only need Porpositional logic, you can use some context-free parser
and implement resolution as recursive operations on nested dictionary representations
of logic oerators, I once did this with Early parser and it was a quite useful tool.

http://pyke.sourceforge.net/

https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sgc/teaching/pre2012/v231/lecture8.html

Comment: At the moment I am doing this without considering the contextual knowledge. For entity extraction I have used , Dependency Parser based approach, which deals with a verb of a given sentence. However I have  to assume that the state of the each entity should be given. For an example: If the Door is opened =>1(Binary Value)